# Design a circuit using only 2 to 1 multiplexers that implements the function of an 8 to 1 multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic

I'm not entirely familiar with multiplexers and I don't fully understand the concept of how I can make a 2 to 1 imitate a 8 to 1. Is there a predetermined/default truth table for multiplexers that I do not know about? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has been asked before. Of course there is a truth table for a multiplexer! Did you search anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a couple of weeks late, but at least this should improve on the answers.

2:1 MUX compact truth-table, followed by schematic:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
   S
 & Y \\
\hline
0 & I0 \\
1 & I1 \\
\end{array}
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK0BCg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

8:1 MUX truth-table, followed by schematic (each MUX is a set of not, and and or gates as shown above):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
   S2
 & S1
 & S0
 & Y \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & A \\
0 & 0 & 1 & B \\
0 & 1 & 0 & C \\
0 & 1 & 1 & D \\
1 & 0 & 0 & E \\
1 & 0 & 1 & F \\
1 & 1 & 0 & G \\
1 & 1 & 1 & H \\
\end{array}
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDze3j.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The clue is that you're using '2 to 1 multiplexer**s**' to implement an 8 to 1 multiplexer.

Start with your eight inputs, feed these into some 2 to 1 multiplexers. Continue adding multiplexers until you have one output.

Comment: aaaah, but how do you derive the logic to control them all? :-)

Comment: Using the one ring! (Or in this case the correct wiring, which is trivial.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUKKSq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>